# XNA game embedded in website

Tags: web, xna

I just finished a game in XNA, and I was wondering if it could be played in the web browser (using silverlight, for example.) I am using webs.com to make my website, so I don't know if it gives me the full capabilities (I have the free version.) All help would be greatly appreciated. If anybody does know how, please attempt to explain it thuroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but no, you can't do it *directly*, there is no `Game` class in Silverlight. 
But you can try to port it to [Silverlight 5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2011/10/05/silverlight-5-brings-xna-3d-to-the-web.aspx) if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using 2D graphics, you can use the SilverSprite library to import images similarly to how you use the sprite/spritebatch.

Here is a link with a video demoing how its used.
http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Continuum/SilverSprite

Answer (score 0):

Could always create a WPF xbap application and host the XNA content within that.

There is a fantastic article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38301/XNA-integration-inside-WPF) that explains how to host XNA content within' WPF, not sure if it'll work in xbap partial trust but always worth a shot.